# How to remove a global ajax event handler in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

It might seem like not a very sophisticated question (I really am a novice in JQuery), but here's my problem:

Every time a specific button is clicked on my website, I need to attach a function which registers a global ajax event handler (.ajaxSend, to be exact) and checks the options of the ajax request.

However, since the button can be clicked multiple times, I need to remove the handler somehow so that the next button click doesn't attach a new event handler again, which will result in stacking up event handlers.

In case you wonder, I can not attach a callback to a specific ajax request since I include the code via Google Tag Manager custom HTML tag (if you know what I'm saying)

Answer (score 7):

The `ajaxSend` function is just a wrapper for `.on('ajaxSend', ...)`

You should therefore be able to use `$(document).off('ajaxSend')` to remove all existing handlers.

Comment: how can I detach a specific handle from .ajaxSend then?

Comment: if you have a reference to the handler, just pass it as the second argument.